# I can't show up the captured image in the thumbnails

Tags: android-studio

its a class assignment and I need to finish it today.
So basically the captured image is saved but it won't show up in the imgVpic imageview camera open up and the image captured is saved correctly with the correct file name but it just won't show up in the thumbnail that I set up, I checked in the gallery and the picture is there but again .. the image won't show in this imgVpic image view (i kept repeating this cause I can't post this question without "more details" since my post is mostly code, pls help I'm a student and I hate my teacher)

here is the code that I used

public class CaptureImgActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
final int CAMERA_RESULT=0;
Uri imgUri=null;
Button btTakePic;
ImageView imgVPic;

private void CaptureImageUri(){
        String dir= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();
        File folder=new File(dir + File.separator+"test");
        boolean success=true;

        if (!folder.exists()){
            try {
                success=folder.mkdir();
                Toast.makeText(this,"Folder Create Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (Exception e){
                success = !success;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    if (success){
        dir=dir+ File.separator+"test";
    }

    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

    File file= new File(dir,"test"+(calendar.getTimeInMillis()+".jpg"));
    if (!file.exists()){
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            imgUri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(CaptureImgActivity.this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,file);
            Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imgUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_RESULT);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else {
        try {

            file.delete();

            file.createNewFile();

            imgUri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(CaptureImgActivity.this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,file);
            Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imgUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_RESULT);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT && requestCode == RESULT_OK){
        try {
                Uri imgUri=data.getData();
                Bitmap bitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imgUri);
                imgVPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_img);

    btTakePic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btTakePic);
    imgVPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVPic);

    btTakePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CaptureImageUri();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in both method like choose image from gallery and Capture Image by adding

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

My Code is Different from yours but work as the same process but this works for me

```
Uri imgUri=null;
protected static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;
protected static final int GALLERY_PICTURE = 1;
private Intent pictureActionIntent = null;
Bitmap bitmap;
String selectedImagePath;


private void SelectImage() {
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            getActivity());
    myAlertDialog.setTitle("Upload Pictures Option");
    myAlertDialog.setMessage("How do you want to set your picture?");

    myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Intent pictureActionIntent = null;

                    pictureActionIntent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(
                            pictureActionIntent,
                            GALLERY_PICTURE);

                }
            });

    myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    imgUri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imgUri);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

                }
            });
    myAlertDialog.show();
}
```

OnActivityResult

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    bitmap = null;
    selectedImagePath = null;

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString());
        for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
            if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                f = temp;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!f.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error while capturing image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 400, 400, true);
            int rotate = 0;
            try {
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getAbsolutePath());
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotate = 270;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotate = 180;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotate = 90;
                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotate);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            //storeImageTosdCard(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE) {
        if (data != null) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath,
                    null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            selectedImagePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath); // load

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And both method works for me and displayed thumbnail

Comment: Just updated my answer what I have followed :) and it works in Android 10 and lower